# 3D movies or videogames from MacBook Pro to 3D projector

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, projector, macos

I have:

- a [3D projector](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CG0QFjAA&url=http://www.benq.com/product/projector/ms513&ei=HeqpT5PRN6mH0AWm-5mbBA&usg=AFQjCNGfn7DrXZKf61rQhGkmeZ111DJh6w) with: HDMI, VGA, S-VIDEO
- [one of the first](http://blog.nakedcellist.org/files/apple-mac-book-pro-2008-edition.jpg) MacBook Pros, with a DVI port (with an ATI X1600)
- DVI to HDMI cable (and a DVI to VGA)
- [Active glasses](http://www.amazon.co.uk/XPAND-X-104-3D-Active-glasses/dp/B00768AVBC), not the red/green (anaglyph) ones

I would like to be able to watch 3D movies being played on the MacBook and watched on the projector.

Question is:

- Is the hardware I have enough?
- If so, what **software** do I need and what video **format** (.mp4, .mkv, etc.)?

I downloaded the [bino](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGwQFjAA&url=http://bino3d.org/&ei=Ka-qT_WDO4TE0QW4yNnkAQ&usg=AFQjCNEjh2e46CaUIxn6z_4jQdIhWkA9Mw) player but seems to be for the red/green kind of glasses.

Answer (score 1):

No - according to the specifications for that projector - they [support set top boxes only and not computer playing DVD](http://www.benq.com/product/projector/3dglasses).

The player they provide runs on Windows and basically draws sequence of frames at double refresh rate so that each eye sees every other frame (they call it side by side) to create the illusion of a 3D scene. There is also reference to 60 Hz refresh rate for over/under (the side by side calls for 120 Hz refresh on the video source)

Your mac can certainly run windows in emulation or in Boot Camp and make use of the provided software. It's not clear if there isn't Mac equivalent software or it's just not linked from this manufacturer's web page, but your display's Dual Link DVI horsepower is certainly fast enough to drive the display in question fast enough to meet the hardware requirements listed for 3D projection.

Comment: Also - if you go into your system profiler and list the actual graphics card you have, it will be more clear if it can drive a signal at 120 Hz. It certainly can drive the 60 Hz input for the over/under mode listed and as long as the video you have is encoded properly it won't matter what package you use to contain the video stream (mkv / mp4 / etc...) when it sits on the filesystem.

Comment: Screen refresh is in the Hz range, not the MHz range. (Frames per second [fps] = frame-Hertz [Hz])

Comment: Holy VHF frequency oops, batman! That would have some [air traffic controllers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_high_frequency#United_States_and_Canada) and [Channel 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_I) fans up in arms if a MacBook were emitting at 60 and 120 MHz. I wish I could say I had pixel clock on my brain, but it was probably a sloppy error rather than recalling the pixel clock rate for dual link DVI.

Comment: There'd be no issue with flicker if screens were refreshed at 60 MHz, though. I wonder how much bandwidth that would take…

Comment: [Single link DVI tops out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Single-link_DVI) at 2.75 megapixels usable resolution at 60 Hz (or about 1900 x 1400 for a 4:3 aspect ratio screen)

Comment: it's a ATI x1600

Comment: do you think this bino player can do the job? http://bino3d.org/download.html